# Invariance & Eigenvalue(s) in finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

I just developed the following question while thinking about invariance in finite dimensions.

> Suppose $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space ($2 \leq n < \infty$), defined over some scalar field $F$ that is not necessarily algebraically closed. Suppose $M$ is an $m$-dimensional subspace in $V$, where $0 < m < n$. Suppose $M$ is invariant under some operator $A$ on $V$. Does it follow that $A$ has at least one Eigenvalue?

I see that the case wherein $F$ is algebraically closed is rather straightforward, and it does even require $M$ to be invariant under $A$. That's because, $F$ is algebraically closed implies that $A$ has an upper-triangular matrix w.r.t. some basis in $V$. This means that $A$ has at least one Eigenvalue. I am unsure what happens in the other case when $F$ is not algebraically closed, and would appreciate a pointer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. An example which I can think of right now (although, some work is required on that) is as follows: Consider $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a direct sum of two two-dimensional hyperplanes. And consider a map which is when restricted to these hyperplanes is a rotation (about the perpendicular axis). Then, I think that the map will not have (real) eigenvalues, yet the two hyperplanes will be invariant.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I thought about this example too :)

Comment: For this kind of questions it may be useful to consider the question from the point of view of $M$. What does it mean for an operator acting on $M$ that there exists a larger $V$ on which the operator can be extended to act, with a fixed given restriction to $M$? The answer is "nothing", as it can be shown that an action on $M$ can _always_ (albeit somewhat arbitrarily) be extended to one on a larger space. So you are basically asking whether _any_ operator on a finite nonzero dimensional space $M$ has an eigenvalue; you should be easily able to see that the answer is "no".

Answer (score 2):

Take $\mathbb{R}^4$. An operator can have the following matrix (in some orthogonal basis):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\alpha) & - \sin(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\
\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha & 0 & 0 \\
0&0& \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
0&0& \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Take, for example, $\alpha = \theta = \pi/4$. Over $\mathbb{R}$ this operator does not have eigenvalues. But it clearly has two orthogonal invariant subspaces.